# Verify encrypted signature using encrypted version of publickey without decrypt them

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, homomorphic-signatures

I try to explain the problem (maybe it's trivial): is there a way to do the following: sign a message with private key, send encrypted version of signature and an encrypted version of publickey to verifier in a manner that the verifier can verify the signature without decrypt publickey and signature?
Thanx in advance for the answer.

Comment: Sure! It can be surely done. You can solve your problem with zero-knowledge proofs. However, the concrete efficiency of your proofs (prover and verifier efficiency and proof size) will depend a lot on the applied signature and encryption scheme. Can you specify which encryption and signature scheme do you need to use?

Comment: Thx Istvan for the quick reply, I don't have any particular constraint on the choice, maybe AES and ECC will do the job

Comment: AES is not so ZKP-friendly. There are a lot of AND gates if you think of the AES function as an arithmetic circuit. You should use a signature and an encryption scheme that is more ZKP friendly. My suggestion would be to use a pairing friendly curve and then e.g., Boneh-Boyen signature scheme with ElGamal-encryption. These two fit well in a Groth-Sahai proof. The knowledge of a Boneh-Boyen signature is quite easy to prove with Groth-Sahai proofs. But, I'm sure there are many other signature  and encryption schemes that can be efficiently be proved with an appropriately chosen ZK proof system.

Comment: Many thx for the suggestion Istvan, I'll take a look to the literature. In the meanwhile, I was thinking about homomorphic encryption in a whitebox context